# AWS Glue: Automatically create new Databases based on S3 path structure

Tags: aws-glue

We have a use case as follows:

1. Our parquet files are stored on S3 in the following structure:

```
s3bucket:/project/deviceid/tbl_message/session/filename.parquet
```

2. We would like to point AWS Glue to crawl this S3 bucket at the 'project' level, i.e. so that any new deviceid entries are added during the crawl.
3. We are able to do this today by creating a new Database manually (i.e. the 'project' level becomes the Database), in which each `tbl_message` level becomes a separate table
4. However, what we would like instead is to have AWS Glue create a new Database for every `deviceid`, in which the `tbl_message` level becomes tables.

The motivation for this is that it allows us to avoid forcing our `tbl_message` names to be 'globally unique' across devices - and it would be easier to work with in our post processing (e.g. for use in AWS Athena + Grafana).

We could solve this by some akward combination of S3 events, AWS Lambda and boto3. But we were hoping for a more elegant solution in which AWS Glue could be set up to leverage the S3 path structure to automatically group the data into separate databases.

Note that the solution needs to be independent of the specific names for the `deviceid` and `tbl_message` levels. A new `device_id` folder is created with a unique 8-character name when a new IoT device connects and starts uploading files.

Can this be done within AWS Glue in a simple dynamic way?